# Network interfaces missing after software update [iMac 7,2]

Tags: imac, software-update, network, system-settings

I recently updated my iMac to Mac OS X 10.6.8, it took a while to come back up, and when it did start up, the network interfaces were missing and when trying to open the Network tab in system preferences, the program just crashes...
Any idea? I'm desperate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the 10.6.8 combo update on another machine and copy it to a thumb drive to run on the machine that's down.

If that fails, I would open a ticket with Apple and let them solve the issue.  There's a fee but it gives you the best way to get the best help.